# How to insert a new line ("\n") character in SQLite?

Tags: c++, sqlite, newline, sql-insert

While trying to insert something like:

```
"Hello\nWorld"
```

SQLite throws error something like:

> Message: unrecognized token: "'Hello";"  (also few other errors)

Even though I convert above string to `"Hello''\nWorld"` or `"Hello\"\n\"World"`, these escape characters sequences don't work in this case.

Currently using C++ language, I am inserting this column like any other simple string columns. I tried above escape sequence (even though I read in internet that, they don't work with `\n`).

How to insert new line and other such special characters in SQLite DB?

Comment: How about `"Hello\\nWorld"`? It also depends on how you express this in code. Better if you could post a code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Nawaz, actually for now in my code, I am simply inserting this new string like any other string and it's failing. It's possible that, the way I am converting the string could be wrong as well. I haven't tried your solution, let me see if it works.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In SQL, there is no mechanism to escape newline characters; you have to insert them literally:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('Hello
world');
```

Alternatively, construct the string dynamically:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('Hello' || char(10) || 'world');
```

(The type of newline (13 or 10 or 13+10) is OS dependent.)

When you embed the SQL statements in C++ strings, you have to escape the newline in the first case:

```c
q1 = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('Hello\nworld');";
q2 = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('Hello' || char(10) || 'world');";
```

Answer (score 0):

### Specific to Qt

To make the Qn generalised, I didn't mention about Qt. For those who use Qt, the multi-line handling is done in [following way](https://wiki.qt.io/QML_Multi-line_Texts_Handling#How_to_Format_a_Multi-line_Text):

```
void InsertToDB (QString contents)
{
  contents.replace("\n", "<br>"); // ... rest will be taken care by Qt
  sqlite.insert<wherever>(contents);
}
```

**Note**: We observe that even typing `<br>` in a text box of Qt, inserts a new line!